# How to define the number of endorsers in Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts

It's not clear to me, how to define the number of endorsers - and what it affects. If we have a single endorser, vs 3 endorsers, vs 10 endorsers - does it affect the technical or organizational side of the blockchain network?

Endorsers are merely for business approvals of a transaction, for example, a bank being an endorser for a buyer procuring supplies on the blockchain? In this case we can have just one endorser - bank organization for a procurement transaction?

Or the number of endorsers affects the technical side of things, for example, ensuring no transaction isolation conflicts on all network nodes?

Answer (score 2):

From the Hyperledger Fabric's glossary:

**Endorser**

> A specific peer role, where the Endorser peer is responsible for simulating transactions, and in turn preventing unstable or non-deterministic transactions from passing through the network.  A transaction is sent to an endorser in the form of a transaction proposal.  All endorsing peers are also committing peers (i.e. they write to the ledger).

In order for all peers of all organization(s) to end up with the same state, a transaction in Hyperledger Fabric goes through three phases.

1. Execute
2. Order
3. Validate

More on [transaction flow](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/txflow.html).

The first note to make here is that there’s a separation between the execution of a transaction (Execute step) and actually updating the ledger (Validate step). This separation has useful effects:

- All peers need to update the ledger, so all peers do the Validate step. But not every peer needs to Execute the smart contract. Hyperledger Fabric uses endorsement policies to define which peers need to execute which transactions. This means that a given chaincode (smart contract) can be kept private from peers that aren’t part of the endorsement policy.
- Transactions can be executed before they are put in order. This allows peers to execute transactions in parallel, which can improve throughput.
- In Fabric’s three-step execute-order-validate model, the results of executing chaincode for a transaction are explicitly agreed upon (according to the endorsement policy) before the transaction is added to the ledger.

**Endorsement policies**:

- Every chaincode has an endorsement policy that specifies the set of peers on a channel that must execute chaincode and endorse the execution results in order for the transaction to be considered valid. These endorsement policies define the organizations (through their peers) who must “endorse” (i.e., approve of) the execution of a proposal.
- As part of the transaction validation step performed by the peers, each validating peer checks to make sure that the transaction contains the appropriate number of endorsements and that they are from the expected sources (both of these are specified in the endorsement policy). The endorsements are also checked to make sure they’re valid (i.e., that they are valid signatures from valid certificates).

Let's consider a scenario where we've two organizations with single peer each(`peer0.org1.example.com`, `peer0.org2.example.com`). Let's say they both are endorsing peers. For some reason, the `peer0.org2.example.com` goes malign(could be due to any reason e.g. secretly & directly changing the world state of a key in peer's associated CouchDB) and starts endorsing fraud transaction proposals. Now, how would our network decide which transaction proposal is valid and which is not as they both are being endorsed by one valid and one invalid? A consensus would never be achieved and the transaction proposal would never reach the subsequent phases and will get rejected. That's why we need to find a balance between security and performance, by setting the correct number of endorsing peers. Generally, more the number of endorsing peers, greater is the chance of mitigating these kinds of attacks.

You can set endorsement policies at many levels:

- [chaincode-level endorsement policie](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/endorsement-policies.html#setting-chaincode-level-endorsement-policies)
- [collection-level endorsement policies](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/endorsement-policies.html#setting-collection-level-endorsement-policies)
- [key-level endorsement policies](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/endorsement-policies.html#setting-key-level-endorsement-policies)

If a peer has chaincode installed on it, **can** act as an endorser. If clients invoke the installed chaincode on the peer, then it **will** act as an endorser.

You can decide whether a particular peer can act as an endorsing peer or not by setting the value of `endorsingPeer` to true/false in [network-config](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/artifacts/network-config.yaml#L55). Though this file belongs to version 1.4 I'm sure you'll find a corresponding network-config in the latest versions as well.

References:

- https://medium.com/kokster/hyperledger-fabric-endorsing-transactions-3c1b7251a709
- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/endorsement-policies.html#endorsement-policies